# Is it possible to access internal jQuery # links (access single website sections directly) from external url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo

I have a single page - auto scroll website template with different `div`s scattered around it.

As stated in the title, can I access those `href` sections directly from an outside url? For example typing http://ozzzi.herobo.com/#about to take me directly to the **ABOUT** section of the single page website?

HTML:

```
<div class="top-nav">
    <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="cbp-spmenu-s2">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
        <a class="scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a class="scroll" href="#features">Features</a>
        <a class="scroll" href="#screenshots">Screen Shots</a>
        <a class="scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
        <a class="scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        <a class="scroll" href="#products">Products</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="main buttonset">    
            <!-- Class "cbp-spmenu-open" gets applied to menu        and "cbp-spmenu-push-toleft" or "cbp-spmenu-push-toright" to the body -->
            <button id="showRightPush"><img src="images/menu.png" alt=""/></button>
            <!--<span class="menu"></span>-->
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
<div class="top-nav">
    <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="cbp-spmenu-s2">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
        <a class="scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a class="scroll" href="#features">Features</a>
        <a class="scroll" href="#screenshots">Screen Shots</a>
        <a class="scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
        <a class="scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        <a class="scroll" href="#products">Products</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="main buttonset">    
            <!-- Class "cbp-spmenu-open" gets applied to menu    and "cbp-spmenu-push-toleft" or "cbp-spmenu-push-toright" to the body -->
            <button id="showRightPush"><img src="images/menu.png" alt=""/></button>
            <!--<span class="menu"></span>-->
    </div>

</pre>
```

another HTML + jQuery example:

```
<pre>  

    <div id="products" class="products wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="products-info">
                <h3>The basic introdution of our Products.</h3>
                <p>Creativity itself doesn't care at all about results - the only thing it craves is the process. 
                Learn to love the process and let whatever happens next happen, 
                without fussing too much about it. </p>
                <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive zoom-img" alt=" " />
                <div class="link">
                    <a href="sign-up.html" class="hvr-shutter-in-vertical">Sign up</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</pre>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        size_li = $("#myList li").size();
        x=1;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
        $('#loadMore').click(function () {
            x= (x+1 <= size_li) ? x+1 : size_li;
            $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
        });
        $('#showLess').click(function () {
            x=(x-1<0) ? 1 : x-1;
            $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've added a link to the template to view it's source in case my explanations weren't good enough:  [**SOURCE**][1]

```
  [1]: http://ozzzi.herobo.com/source
```

Comment: Yes, Give the div a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

In your example #About is a "bookmark" link. Any browser will attempt to scroll to an element with id="About" in the specified page. Just add IDs to each section to want to bookmark. The links can then just have the #bookmarkid value at the end of the URL.